# disregard a line from txt file to excel file in python

Tags: python

I need to disregard lines when someone enters and leaves the channel as you can see in the below txt file.

```
7:52:01 AM sherr entered the channel
7:52:05 AM sherr
hello GOOD morning .
おはようございます。
7:52:09 AM sherr
Who ?
誰?
7:52:16 AM sherr
OK .
わかりました。
7:52:25 AM sherr left the channel.
7:52:32 AM gigi entered the channel
7:52:45 AM gigi
OK .
わかりました。
```

my code is supposed to output excel file that in every 3lines, they're in the same row and 1st line in 1st column, 2nd line in 2nd column and 3rd line in 3rd column. But I need to disregard the lines that has entered the channel and left the channel on it. what should I add?
my codes looks like that as you can see below.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import copy

wb = Workbook()

with open('txtfile.txt', encoding='utf-8') as sherr:
    row = 1
    column = 1
    ws = wb.active
    for line in sherr:
        if column == 1:
            ## split the line and rejoin
            value = " ".join(line.strip().split(' ')[1:])
        else:
            value = line.strip()
            
        ws.cell(row=row, column=column, value=value)
        
        if (column := column + 1) > 3:
            row += 1
            column = 1
 
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:      
            alignment = copy.copy(cell.alignment)
            alignment.wrapText=True
            cell.alignment = alignment
            
    for column_cells in ws.columns:
        length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
        ws.column_dimensions[column_cells[0].column_letter].width = length

    wb.save('txt_to_exl.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension before your first `for` loop to filter out the unwanted lines.

```
with open('txtfile.txt', encoding='utf-8') as sherr:
    row = 1
    column = 1
    ws = wb.active

    lines = [line for line in sherr.readlines()
            if 'entered the channel' not in line
            and 'left the channel' not in line]

    for line in lines:
```

Note that I changed `sherr` to `lines` in at the start of the `for` loop.

The condition above is that lines should be disregarding if they contain the strings 'entered the channel' or 'left the channel', but notice that this could cause unwanted behaviour if somebody happened to include those strings as part of the conversation. You could make this a bit more robust if necessary by checking that the line also begins with a number, etc., or using regular expressions.